# Regarding generating diagrams of flows between the different java classes

Tags: java, uml

I have a project in which there are many different packages, and in those packages there are different Java classes along with interfaces.

I want to draw the class diagram and the relationships between the classes and interfaces, and how the methods flow.

So please advise me a tool which I can install in my Eclipse that will generate those diagrams specially the freeware plugin..!!

Answer (score 1):

I use [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/) to reverse engineer the java classes to generate UML diagrams and it works pretty well, has an option to export the diagrams to image format as well.

If you are okay to NOT reverse-engineer the code and generate diagrams on your own from scratch, then [Violet UML Editor plugin for Eclipse] is a free UML tool. There is a `jnlp` version of this that can be run as an independent application, outside eclipse, too.

Comment: The paid version also lets you generate sequence diagrams +1

Comment: @Brian  It is paid tool, I was looking for freeware to install as plugin in eclipse..!

Comment: @RockySinha It's a paid tool if you want to use it for sequence diagrams. Otherwise, it's free. For reverse-engineered sequence diagrams, I don't think there's a free tool out there that will generate them for you (that I know of, of course).

Answer (score 1):

Check [Visual Paradigm](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/freeumltool/). It is very user friendly and free tool.
Since you are using eclipse you can use the [Eclipse Plugin](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/solution/eclipseuml/) for visual paradigm.

Comment: It is paid tool, I was looking for freeware to install as plugin in eclipse